# What's an umbrella term for the two words "temporary" and "permanent"?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I'm creating a form, by which a user can request access for a specific camera's surveillance tapes.  The user can specify the permanence of the access: either "temporary" or "permanent".  What's a hypernym of the two words? That is, what should I call the form field? Some examples that are off or inaccurate sounding would be: "Access Type", "Access Duration", "Access Permanence"

Comment: How about "Extent of Access"?

Comment: Why not just ask the user: 'Do you want temporary or permanent access'? This is likely to be clearer to the user than any hypernym that anybody might come up with here.

Comment: Nothing is **permanent** in this world. Why not use the concept of term limits and specify the first valid date and the last valid date. If the access does not terminate, either leave the second date blank or “None”. This may seem more cumbersome in the short run, but in the long run it will be easier to describe and use.

Comment: Choosing names for software things is off topic according to our [help].

Answer (score 1):

How about "Term of Access"? (As term refers to a time period, this seems suitable.)